# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: document is not defined in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript

I try to build my first Chrome extension to help copy all tab url that opened in Chrome with specific url. My purpose is when each click the icon extension, the javascript function will run without popup. I only use manifest.json and background.js to try build the extension. but there's issue "ReferenceError: document is not defined" in

```
 var copyFrom = document.createElement("textarea");
```

[image]

I tried with clipboardWrite too but the issue still the same

## **manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Shopee Products URL Copier",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Copy Shopee Products URLs",
    "action": {
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "icon16.png",
        "48": "icon48.png",
        "128": "icon128.png"
      }
    },
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "tabs",
      "clipboardWrite"
    ],
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "icons": {
      "16": "icon16.png",
      "48": "icon48.png",
      "128": "icon128.png"
    }
}
```

## **background.js**

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(() => {
  const urlPattern1 = /^https:\/\/shopee\.co\.id\/.*-i\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/;
  const urlPattern2 = /^https:\/\/shopee\.co\.id\/product\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/;
  const urlPattern3 = /^https:\/\/shopee\.co\.id\/xx-i\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/;

  chrome.tabs.query({}, (tabs) => {
    let matchedArray = [];

    tabs.forEach((tab) => {
      var tabURLs = tab.url;
      if (urlPattern1.test(tabURLs) || urlPattern2.test(tabURLs) || urlPattern3.test(tabURLs)) {
        matchedArray.push(tabURLs);
      }
    });

    var urlList = matchedArray.join('\n');
    
    async function copyTextToClipboard(text) {

      var copyFrom = document.createElement("textarea");
    

      copyFrom.textContent = text;
    

      document.body.appendChild(copyFrom);
    

      copyFrom.select();
    

      document.execCommand('copy');

      copyFrom.blur();
    

      document.body.removeChild(copyFrom);
    }

    copyTextToClipboard(urlList);

  })
  
});
```

how to solve the issue and is my step correct?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, ***[search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=ReferenceError:+document+is+not+defined%22+chrome+extension+site:stackoverflow.com)***;